# How to combine multiple lines based on values that are identical

Tags: python

I have a list of text lines that I want to be combined based on identical values on the right side of the delimiter ":"  If the values on the right are identical then combine the lines with appending the left side of the delimiter and keeping only one copy of the right side of the delimiter.

List:

```
file1: apple
file2: car
file1: car
file3: people
file4: stuff
file5: people
```

Desired_list:

```
file1:       apple
file2,file1: car
file3,file5: people
file4:       sutff
```

Comment: Seems like you could use either a) a dictionary or b) a matrix with files as rows and the other things as columns (like a `CountVectorizer` object).

Comment: I'm not sure how to approach it.  If you could give a hint I could try it out..

Comment: My list is just a file in the format I've shown above.

Answer (score 0):

You want to split the lines based on the delimiter, and then add them to a list embedded in a dictionary. I like to use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects) for this.

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for line in textfile:
    fname, val = line.split(':')
    d[val.strip()].append(fname.strip())

for key in d:
    print ','.join(d[key]) + ':' + key
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a lot of ways.

Here is one way to do it by using a dictionary as a helper data structure.

I've created a dictionary and i store each right side value as a key and the left value as a value and if the key is already exist, i'm appending to the value the relevant file.

At the end, I'm converting the dictionary into the required list.

```
li = ["file1: apple","file2: car","file1: car","file3: people","file4: stuff","file5: people"]

tmp_dict = {}
for item in li:
    l, r  = item.split(":")
    tmp_dict[r] = tmp_dict[r] + "," + l if tmp_dict.has_key(r) else l

res = [v + ":" + k for k,v in tmp_dict.items()]

print res

>>> ['file4: stuff', 'file2,file1: car', 'file1: apple', 'file3,file5: people']
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try.